# calculating width for "Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements"

Tags: html, css

CSS 2.2 Spec for [10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) says:

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then, if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static position and apply rule number three below; otherwise, set 'right' to the static position and apply rule number one below.
>
> If none of the three is 'auto': If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values, unless this would make them negative, in which case when direction of the containing block is 'ltr' ('rtl'), set 'margin-left' ('margin-right') to zero and solve for 'margin-right' ('margin-left'). If one of 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' is 'auto', solve the equation for that value. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.

I was playing with these rules. In one case I set `left`, `right` and `width`, not an `auto` value, but I am not getting how right value is affecting the layout. To me it seems it has no effect, like the **used value** of `right` is set to `0` (`0` is my guess as browser devtool shows the value as `5px`). Can anyone explain if my guess is correct or not? If not then how it is applying in the layout, because I am not able to justify it from the documentations of the spec above.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffe;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.child {
  background: #ee2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I am positioned
  </div>
</div>
```

the display is like:

[image: Absolute Positioning]

Comment: Your assumption is correct. If you don't set value for "left", then browser will use the value of "right" to position your child div, 5px from right.

Comment: @neo Yeah. I was not able to find it in the spec before I asked here. Now I got it [there](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#relative-positioning).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stickers has MDN's version. The relevant portion of the text from your citation itself is in the last sentence, which corroborates with MDN's interpretation (MDN simply uses different terminology that may be more accessible to web developers):

> If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.

The term "over-constrained" is defined in section 10.3.3 however:

> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value.

Answer (score 3):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) article explains it clearly:

> When both `left` and `right` are defined, the position of the element is *overspecified*. When this is the case, the `left` value has precedence when the container is left-to-right (thus, the computed value of `right`  is set to `-left`); the right value has precedence when the container is right-to-left (thus, the computed value of `left` is set to `-right`).